How to overcome "This document requires 'TrustedHTML' assignment" error?
I've been using bookmarklets with eval and a base64 string of the code for ages and suddenly my scripts won't work on some pages, where they used to work. How can I overcome this?
This is the error:

Uncaught EvalError: Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because this document requires 'Trusted Type' assignment.

Example bookmarklet:
// bookmarklet = toBase64Bookmarklet(function() {console.log('Hello world!')})
javascript:eval(atob('Y29uc29sZS5sb2coJ0hlbGxvIHdvcmxkIScp'))

I know (I think) what I am doing and would like to revert to the previous security setting.
/edit
This doesn't seem to be an eval specific issue as I got this error right away, when trying something else.

Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'insertAdjacentHTML' on 'Element': This document requires 'TrustedHTML' assignment.


toBase64Bookmarklet()

Could you share some public page where I can reproduce this?

please try doing something like javascript:(function(){console.log('Hello world!')})(); by using an IIFE instead of eval ... since Trusted Types locks down injection sinks like Functions that execute code such as eval(). So I guess the site you are trying to interact with enforces it also to prevent what you are trying to do there. My suggestion goes with console.log but you are probably trying to change the dom instead

@DiegoD My actual code is hundreds lines long and it is much more comfortable to move around as a base64 string. Also, the issue is not just the eval but also dom manipulation and my guess is even more. Good read nonetheless, thanks!

@0stone0 YouTube

@Qwerty yes eval was just one of the 4 things listed as locked down in the link I shared before. There's no guess.. it's written clearly in the mdn docs explicitely

So Diego's link explains it quite well; it's a CORS setting that prevents stuff like you're trying to do ;)

I made the DOM insertion work, but I didn't figure out the trusted script yet. Will try it later and write an answer.

@Qwerty did you ever figure out an answer? I have a similar issue with my bookmarklet which download js file to the page.

@Rafi yes, I let ChatGPT to rewrite my dom commands to createElement and appendChild, etc. And instead of eval I used online js uglifier tool to format my code to a single line. see here and look at the README for my notes too.
